# Azure information protection labels and office protection labels are not syncronising

Tags: azure, office365, azure-information-protection

In AIP under global policy I have created some labels but there are not synchronizing with office protection classification labels, I have reffered [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPe6o0Z2fBM). Can anyone suggest what part I am missing in the process
thanks .

> Currently I am having office 365 enterprise E3 edition  subscription with P1 license for users.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deleting the existing policy file and try authenticating again with the app?